# Complex calculated fields and values with react-final-form inside Edit

Tags: react-admin

I am developing a complex Edit form which includes over 200 fields, roughly half of them are calculated by using values from other fields, in some cases formulas refer to values from multiple other fields.

I am trying to use react-final-form's `<Form\>` inside react-admin's Edit. I cannot figure out how to reference more than one field in the decorator, for some reason *allValues* is only visible before "=>" in the update statement. It seems to be working fine outside of react-admin but not when integrated in the react-admin's Edit.

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532

    77 |        field: ["Field1"], 
    78 |        updates: {
  > 79 |            Field2: (Field1Value, allValues) => Field1Value + allValues.Field3 * 10
       |                                                              ^
    80 |        }
    81 |    }
    82 |
```

Another issue is that I cannot find a way to refer to the form's values, "values" prop is not populated when the Form is used inside of Edit.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use an array as a field value. the concept of react final form decorator is to find a change in any field and you can mutate other fields accordingly. That is the reason you cannot pass array as a field value.

```
{
  field: 'product_code', // if product_code changes
  updates: {
    bill_amount: (product_code, allValues) => do some calculations,
    total_discount: (product_code, allValues) => do some calculations
  }
}
```

I also have some code example for you as I recently work with final form decorator

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).